# Can not send event to google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

does any body knows whey can't send event to google analytics??

code:

```
 GAServiceManager.getInstance().setDispatchPeriod(20);
 GoogleAnalytics mGaInstance;
 Tracker mGaTracker1; 
 mGaInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity());
 mGaInstance.setDebug(true);
 mGaTracker1 = mGaInstance.getTracker(Consts.ANALYTICS);    
 mGaTracker1.sendEvent("aa", "bb", "cc", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't used it to send custom events or data this api docs seem to imply that it is possible.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/customdimsmets

Please note that if you see the send in logcat then it did get sent but it will take up to 24hours before you start seeing anything in the analytic web reporting site.